# Rename "Group Input" socket in geometry nodes in Blender 3.3.1

Tags: geometry-nodes

When editing geometry nodes for an object I can request new values by adding sockets to the Group Input node. However, I can't work out how to rename those sockets. For instance, in this geometry nodes setup, I'd like to rename the indicated "Value" to something a bit more useful, such as "Start Frame". How do I do that? I'm using Blender 3.3.1.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open sidebar, and select group tab. Here you can see the list of inputs and outputs that you can edit:

[image]

Comment: Aha! The Group tab! I didn't even notice that there were tabs there. Thank you!